# Direct file access from memory on Android 11

Tags: android, android-11

My application interacts with some pdf reports which come from "**outside**" and stays in Download folder (Reports are downloaded by user via browser).

**My goal** is to open this pdf reports with external PDF-Viewer. Like Google Docs (or others).

**My code** looks like this:

```
    final String reportName="/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.pdf";
    File file = new File(reportName);
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    target.setDataAndType(fileURI,"application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(target.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(target, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Log.d("FileWorker","Size is"+resInfoList.size());
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
        context.grantUriPermission(packageName, fileURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
    startActivity(target);
```

Everything worked fine on API level below 30.
On Android 30 this doesn't work, fails with (from logs):

```
com.google.android.apps.docs E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
com.google.android.apps.docs E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : 1.pdf] +ContentOpenable, uri: content://org.qtproject.example.provider/root/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.pdf
```

I guess this happens because of Scoped Storage politics.

**What I've tried**:

- Getting PDF file URI with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and file picker. And then use this URI with ACTION_VIEW. This works fine, but I don't really want to use file picker.
- I know about `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`, but it won't work on Android 30.
- I've tried adding queries in Manifest like this:

  ```
     <queries>
       <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.docs"/>
       <intent>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

      <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
      </intent>
     </queries>
  ```

Dosen't help either.

Anything I can do to fix this issue besides using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Comment: Use file.exists() before you get a target. And file.canRead(). If it is not your apps file, and it is not, then your app cannot read it.

Comment: So ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is your friend.